# How does a non-null annotation on a generic argument propagate to its uses?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, annotations

I'm trying to annotate a generic class' type argument use with `@NonNull`s:

```java
interface Func<@NonNull U, @NonNull V> {
    V apply(U u);
}

public class SomeClass<@NonNull T> {

     // 1.
     public static <T> SomeClass<T> factory();

     // 2.
     public SomeClass<T> method(SomeClass<? extends T> other);

     // 3.
     public <R> SomeClass<R> transform(Func<T, R> f);
}
```

There are 3 cases I'm not sure about:

1. Does the `SomeClass<T>` in the static method get the `@NonNull` from the declaration or do I have to specify `<@NonNull T>` again?
2. Do I have to specify `SomeClass<@NonNull ? extends T>` due to the covariant use?
3. Do I have to specify `<@NonNull R>` here or does `SomeClass<R>` or `Func<T, R>`'s declared annotations propagate? Do I have to annotate as `Func<@NonNull T, @NonNull R>` again?

The classes are expected to be used from Kotlin too, which has non-nullness included in its type system. Would Kotlin need more annotations declared beyond the example given, such as cases 1..3?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such type as `SomeClass<@Nullable Integer>`, but `SomeClass<@NonNull Integer>` and `SomeClass<@NonNull String>`.  You do not have to add any constraints to the declaration of `factory()`.
2. Since `T` is non-null, any subtype of it is also non-null.  You don't need a redundant `@NonNull`.
3. `transform()` can only be instantiated with `R` non-null, so you don't need to change the declaration to `<@NonNull R>`, but there is no harm in doing so.